Show that $\sqrt[3]{4(x+y)} \geq \sqrt[3]{x}+ \sqrt[3]{y}$ if and only if $x=y$ or $\sqrt[3]{x}+ \sqrt[3]{y} \geq 0$
The problem
Show that $\sqrt[3]{4(x+y)} \geq \sqrt[3]{x}+ \sqrt[3]{y}$, if and only if $x=y$ or $\sqrt[3]{x}+ \sqrt[3]{y} \geq 0$
My idea
c_1: If we know that $x=y$ or $\sqrt[3]{x}+ \sqrt[3]{y} \geq 0$
a) $x=y$ then we can simply verify $2\sqrt[3]{x}\leq \sqrt[3]{8 \cdot x}$ which verifies with equality
b) $\sqrt[3]{x}+ \sqrt[3]{y} \geq 0$ then the inequality is $$\begin{split}\sqrt[3]{4(x+y)} \geq \sqrt[3]{x}+ \sqrt[3]{y} \geq 0 &\Leftrightarrow 4x+4y \geq x+y+3\sqrt[3]{x^2y}+ 3\sqrt[3]{xy^2}\\
&\Leftrightarrow 3x+3y \geq 3\sqrt[3]{x^2y}+ 3\sqrt[3]{xy^2}\end{split}$$ which is true by AM-GM
I dont know what i should do for the other case where we know the inequality and we show that $x=y$ or $\sqrt[3]{x}+ \sqrt[3]{y} \geq 0$
Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

Surely for any $n$-root there is a constant like $4$ that gives us an inequality.

@calculatormathematical I thought of using CBS maybe because we cand use AM-GM

I don't understand your step "which is true by AM-GM".

All we need is to do similar calculations as yours
$$ \sqrt[3]{4(x+y)}\geq \sqrt[3]x+\sqrt[3]y \Longleftrightarrow 4(x+y)\geq x+y +3\sqrt[3]{x^2y}+3\sqrt[3]{xy^2}\Longleftrightarrow $$
$$ \Longleftrightarrow 3x+3y\geq 3\sqrt[3]{x^2y}+3\sqrt[3]{xy^2}\Longleftrightarrow x+y -\sqrt[3]{x^2y}-\sqrt[3]{xy^2}\geq 0\Longleftrightarrow $$
$$ \Longleftrightarrow (\sqrt[3]x+\sqrt[3]y)(\sqrt[3]{x^2}-\sqrt[3]{xy}+\sqrt[3]{y^2})-\sqrt[3]{xy}(\sqrt[3]x+\sqrt[3]y)\geq 0 \Longleftrightarrow$$
$$ \Longleftrightarrow (\sqrt[3]x+\sqrt[3]y)(\sqrt[3]{x^2}-2\sqrt[3]{xy}+\sqrt[3]{y^2})\geq0 \Longleftrightarrow (\sqrt[3]x+\sqrt[3]y)(\sqrt[3]x-\sqrt[3]y)^2\geq 0 $$
but the right side is true iff $\sqrt[3]x+\sqrt[3]y \geq 0$ or $\sqrt[3]x=\sqrt[3]y$ because the second factor is a square so it's nonnegative

The case with $xy=0$ can be trivially proved, then for $xy\neq 0$, since $A\ge B \iff A^3 \ge B^3$, by $\frac x y=a^3$ we have
$$\sqrt[3]{4(x+y)} \geq \sqrt[3]{x}+ \sqrt[3]{y} \iff x-\sqrt[3]{x^2y}-\sqrt[3]{xy^2}+y \ge 0 \iff y(a-1)^2(a+1)\ge 0$$
Now, suppose that $y<0$ then the latter inequality leads to $a \le -1$ or $a=1$ with

$a=1 \implies x=y$
$a=-1 \implies x=-y>0$
$a<-1 \implies x>-y>0$

therefore, excluding the case $x=y$, at least one among $x$ and $y$ is positive and assuming wlog $y>0$ the inequality leads to $a \ge -1$ that is $\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y}\ge 0$ with $x=y$ for $a=1$.

I have 2 questuions 1) How did you introduced a in the inequality and 2) why are you able to $|^3$. Shouldnt we look if the sign of the inequality changes?

Yes I indeed I need to make clearer some steps! I fix it

@PamMunozRyan I've tried to make things more complete and clear, let me know if it better now! Thanks
